# return nth element of binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree which I am trying to use a get method to return the nth item, but i am really struggling to work out how to do so

```
public A get(int index){
}
```

As you can see I'm passing an int to the method, this will be the nth element, could someone please point me in the correct direction

Comment: What kind of BST implementation are you using?

Comment: Do the nodes in your BST know the size of their subtree?

Comment: @m_callens I'm unsure what you mean by that?

Comment: Can you please post the code for your BST class as well

Comment: @ruakh yes I have a maethod which returns the size of left and right

Comment: @iainman You need to frame your question better and also add code, so that people understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @iainman: Does that method *calculate* the sizes? Or is the size of a subtree stored in its own field?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a breadth-first search using a queue. Here a pseudo-code:

```
BreadthFirstSearch(Node root) {
    Queue Q;
    Node n;
    Q.insert(root);

    while(Q.isEmpty != true) {
        n = Q.extract();

        if n->leftSon != null
            Q.insert(n->leftSon);

        if n->rightSon != null
            Q.insert(n->rightSon);
    }
}
```

In your case, you can modify this code and could create a counter and use it in a do-while's condiction. For example, you can do something like that:

```
BreadthFirstSearch(Node root, int nthItem) {
    Queue Q;
    Node n;
    Q.insert(root);
    int i=0; 


    do {
        n = Q.extract();

        if n->leftSon != null
            Q.insert(n->leftSon);

        if n->rightSon != null
            Q.insert(n->rightSon);

        i++;
    } while(Q.isEmpty != true && i != nthItem);

    return n;            
}
```

Use this method in your getNthItem(int nthItem) method. Once it return the item you can handle it.
It not the best code ever, but it's just to make you an idea.

Comment: Here you can see how the breadth-first search works for a common graph: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRq6p9s8NVg